# How can I transfer details from a texture or normal map to a mesh (for 3d printing a model)

Tags: uv, normal-map, 3d-printing

I'm working on printing a 3D model (a rifle from Overwatch), but there are some details that are only present in the texture/normal maps and not the model.  I've been trying to find a way to transfer those details to the mesh for printing.

Steps I have tried:

Baking - Ran for a bit then... there was no visible change, just removed some portions of the texture that were not linked to the specific model.  The mesh itself was unchanged.  I'm assuming there is a setting I'm missing/doing wrong but I can not for the life of me figure it out.

Displacement Modifier - this ... just explodes the model.  Literally it looks like it exploded outwards.  Even at the lowest strength it's just a mess with no details transferred.

Everything I've searched points to using one of those methods but I'm clearly doing something wrong.  The only thing I can think of is that the model has an existing UV map that is pretty complex.  I tried unwrapping it but I really don't have a way to re-associate the sections to the model.

I get the feeling there is something very simple I'm missing - so if I'm doing a dumb feel free to let me know.

Here is a pic of the model and (what I assume is) the height map.  I also have a normal map which looks the same, just in purple shades)

[image: Model with height map refrence]

I was able to apply that to a plane as well:
[image: I was able to apply that to a plane as well:]

so have to figure if I can map that to the model itself I guess.

Edit/Update:

Just trying to get one second working right now, so ignore the rest, but it's starting to shape up.  I'm assuming I need to clean up the map I'm using to deal with some of the odd lines/general mess.

[image: it's progress]

Comment: there are ways to convert normal map to bump map, and then Displacement should work, it's hard to help if you don't give some pictures, maybe show the normal map you're using and we can try on a plane

Comment: @moonboots - I was able to find a height map and I added pictures.  I was able to apply that to a plane, so now I have to figure out how to do that to the model itself.

Comment: in the Displace modifier, you can choose Texture Coordinate > UV Map, so what you need to do is to unwrap your object and put the parts where they are supposed to be over the height map. And of course your object need to be subdivided enough.

Comment: Getting some progress, re doing the UV mapping is no fun, but starting to get there.  Still a bit messy but I assume I need to do some clean up on the map I'm using to deal with that.  I've only re-mapped the 'axe' part for now, so the rest of the model due to that.  Once i have that section sorted I can get the rest of the mess lined back up.